# SQL query simplifier tool

Tags: database, sql

I need a tool to simplify queries like:

```
select usertourna0_.id as id64_0_, usertourna0_.timestamp as timestamp64_0_ from some_table_name usertourna0_ where usertourna0_.id=:p0 and  not (1=0) order by usertourna0_.timestamp desc limit :p1;:p0 = 8570 [Type: Int32 (0)];:p1=123 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

to

```
select t.id, t.timestamp from some_table_name t where t.id=8750 order by t.timestamp desc limit 123
```

meaning removing not used aliases and redundant conditions, replacing long table alias names like "usertourna0_" with short, specifying parameter values.

It's better to have this as a .NET library but any other app that I can use on Windows is suitable. In case it's not free, the price should be in indie capabilities and the limit depends on other available features.